# How to put default values for a map in AVRO IDL

Tags: serialization, deserialization, avro

I have a record and in the record there is a map and I want to put a default value for a map.  I was looking at this link but there is no example with a map
http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/idl.html

Answer (score 4):

All default values should be defined in JSON serialization format.

So, a record with a default map would look like:

```
record DefaultMap {
  map<string> test = {"Hello" : "world", "Merry" : "Christmas"};
}
```